# HTML Random Dot on webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a web page here: http://dev.jmret.com/eduforschools.php

For some reason there is a random dot just above recent news which i cannot get rid of. i have tried google inspect element to find the code that's doing it but it doesn't show.

i'm not sure if its a styling issue or html issue, help fixing it would be much appreciated. I know its not the PHP code as that is being used on several other pages without a problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add this to override the default `list-style` on all lists:

```
li {list-style: none; }
```

But before you do this, check your code,, you cant use `<li>` without `<ul>` or `<ol>`  
examples:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
<ul>
<ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
<ol>
```

Check your website at https://validator.w3.org/ for errors

Answer (score 0):

Add     `list-style: none;`
to your `.body-section` Please note that it will only override deafult styles for the current css class. To override all `LI` use more common selector.
That's not a random dot but a default list item styling.

Also check your mark-up: you have `li` not nested in `ul`

About other pages: there you have a valid structure. Please compare it with the page above.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, any reason why it is ONLY on that page then? And not others that are using the exact same template etc.

Comment: 1. The dot is also presented in footer. 2. Show other page and we'll help you inspect.

Comment: http://dev.jmret.com/index.php - uses exact same html template with minor edits any page you can navagate to is just a modified base html template i setup

Answer (score 0):

it is styling issue. that dot is because you have a list item. add this into your `<ul>` code `<ul type="none">` or achieve it through css its your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.body-section {
  list-style: none;
}

.footer-section {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this is would help you everywhere.

```
*{
  list-style: none;
 }
```